# Vertical center aligning text for responsive

Tags: css

I removed a lot of code so the below is the bare minimum.

How would I align the text below to be both vertically/horizontally centered and auto adjusts when going responsive?

I excluded the @media css. But without altering too much of what I have, is there a way so that the text will be centered even when it bumps to two or even three lines?

When you runt he code snippet below, notice how option 1 and option two are not centered.

I left in the JS so you can see what I'm doing, it's just a navigation.

```js
//Make first one active
$(".tabs > li ").first().addClass("activeTab");

$(".tabs > li").click(function(e) {

  $(".activeTab ").removeClass("activeTab");

  var _this = $(this);
  _this.addClass("activeTab");
});
```

```css
.tabs_accordion {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.tabs_accordion > input {
  display: none;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #7EE8FF;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li {
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 238px;
  position: relative;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label {
  display: block;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid yellow;
  margin: 0px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > label {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > div {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs {
  display: table;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > label {
  display: none;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > div {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* For Java */

/* ARROW Controls */

Controls Active .tabs_accordion [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.activeTab {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 74px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover label:after,
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li.activeTab label:after {
  display: block;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover label {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover + li > label {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_accordion">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_1" id="tab_1_content_control" checked="checked" tabindex="0" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_2" id="tab_2_content_control" tabindex="0" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_3" id="tab_3_content_control" tabindex="0" />

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <label for="tab_1_content_control">Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="tab_2_content_control">Option two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="tab_3_content_control">Optionofand optionss shdfkshdkfh</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">

    <label for="tab_1_content_control">Option 1</label>
    <label for="tab_2_content_control">Option two</label>
    <label for="tab_3_content_control">Optionofand optionss shdfkshdkfh</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you can do is remove the `padding` from the label and make the `line-height` same as the `height` of the label.

This is one of the tricks that works when there is only one line of text like in your case.

**Code**:

```
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label {
      display: block;
      height: 74px;
      line-height:74px;
      text-align: center;
      border-left: 2px solid yellow;
      margin: 0px 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
 }
```

**Example**:

```js
//Make first one active
$(".tabs > li ").first().addClass("activeTab");

$(".tabs > li").click(function(e) {

  $(".activeTab ").removeClass("activeTab");

  var _this = $(this);
  _this.addClass("activeTab");
});
```

```css
.tabs_accordion {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.tabs_accordion > input {
  display: none;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #7EE8FF;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li {
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 238px;
  position: relative;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label {
  display: block;
  height: 74px;
  line-height:74px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid yellow;
  margin: 0px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > label {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > div {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs {
  display: table;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > label {
  display: none;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > div {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* For Java */

/* ARROW Controls */

Controls Active .tabs_accordion [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.activeTab {
  background-color: blue;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 74px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover label:after,
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li.activeTab label:after {
  display: block;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover label {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover + li > label {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_accordion">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_1" id="tab_1_content_control" checked="checked" tabindex="0" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_2" id="tab_2_content_control" tabindex="0" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_3" id="tab_3_content_control" tabindex="0" />

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <label for="tab_1_content_control">Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="tab_2_content_control">Option two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="tab_3_content_control">Optionofand optionss shdfkshdkfh</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">

    <label for="tab_1_content_control">Option 1</label>
    <label for="tab_2_content_control">Option two</label>
    <label for="tab_3_content_control">Optionofand optionss shdfkshdkfh</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, however it doesn't help when I do have more than one line. Some of the links go to two or even three lines when going responsive. The code you provided you can see the text floating out below the block.

Comment: Oh that's too bad, i've considered removing the `height` and adjusting the `padding` which does center it,but that will also require you to adjust the top property of the arrow to make it display correctly. In the end i opted for the `line-height` solution.